# mod_rewrite - check for existing files and directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domain names, `foo.com` and `bar.com` and a `.htaccess` file at the root of `bar.com` asking all requests to `bar.com` to redirect to `foo.com` except the initial search for a directory index file, which gets pointed to a specific php file (`functions.php`) at `foo.com`.

This means that a request for `bar.com` or `www.bar.com` will see `foo.com/functions.php` accessed and the various requests for images, stylesheets etc. continue to access the rewritten relative path of `foo.com/images/image.jpg` rather than `foo.com/function.phpimages/image.jpg`. **This all works fine**.

Now, the problem.

I want to include a subdirectory on `bar.com` that doesn't redirect. As in, a request for `bar.com/newdirectory/` goes to that directory and all relative file requests behave as normal while keeping the original rule (described above) for anyone accessing `bar.com` at root. Currently I get a 404 if I try and access the new subdirectory.

In my original `.htaccess` file I had included a loose code for checking that files do not exist. I tried adding the flag `!-d` to check if directories don't exist first but this has resulted in requests to `bar.com` going straight to `foo.com` rather than `foo.com/functions.php`

**Current `.htaccess` file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Check the request isn't an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.foo.com/functions.php [P]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.foo.com/$1 [P]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add after `RewriteBase /` :

```
RewriteRule ^newdirectory/? - [L]
```

And for others. No need to test file, because you redirect empty URI only.
You can use :

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.foo.com/functions.php [P]
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.foo.com/$1 [P]
```

**Which gives for all `.htaccess`:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^newdirectory/? - [L]

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.foo.com/functions.php [P]
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://www.foo.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: This does appear to work, thanks Croises. I wonder if there's a solution that will work for futureproofing new subdirectories? I can manually add exemptions in, like this, for the moment.

Comment: You can test with `RewriteRule ^(newdirectory|otherdirectory|other|other)/? - [L]`

Comment: Or add a number after and use always the same name, with `RewriteRule ^newdirectory\d*/? - [L]` for newdirectory, newdirectory1, newdirectory2, 3, 4...

Comment: I was still looking for something more along the lines of using a variables rather than defined strings but, you know what, I've come around to thinking that having exact control on this and manually entering strings might be better and may prefer this way now.

Comment: Yes, and with final number it still gives a lot of flexibility. Just add `\d*` after your directory name.

Comment: Patience, have to leave the computer sometimes ;)